# What is the purpose of specifying the type of argument a main method takes in?

Tags: java, oop, types, arguments

`public static void main (string[] args)` is a main method which must be given an array of strings as arguments.

However, when I run a program, the main method automatically runs without me needing to explicitly call it with arguments.

Therefore, I have the following questions:

- Does the type of argument of a main method matter?
- Are there situations in which one would explicitly call the main method with arguments? If so, what is an example of such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the type of argument of a main method matter?

Yes.  The JVM uses `public static main(String[] args)` as the entry point of execution for general Java applications.  In other words, this is where the JVM is going to hand off execution from its own internal loading and initialization routines to your own bytecode.  Unless you are executing an application inside a container (eg. GlassFish) or framework (eg. JavaFX) you will need to have this entry point for your code.  By convention it is `public static main(String...)`.

> Are there situations in which one would explicitly call the main
>   method with arguments? If so, what is an example of such a situation?

Arguments to `main(...)` come mainly from two places:

- The Command line.  When you start a Java application from the command line inside a shell or Windows `cmd.exe`, you can type in some additional data after the name of the JAR file to execute.  These additional data are processed into an array of Strings that is passed to your `main()` method.
- A configuration setting.  Most IDE's allow you to specify command line parameters for a project.  You can pass parameters to the entry point (when you build and run your project) in this setting just as you would on the command line.

As mentioned by Dave, your own code would not invoke the `main(...)` method itself.  It really is intended to just be the entry point.

Comment: when i type `java  File`  in the command line without any arguments after `File` , am i just giving main an empty string as an argument?

Comment: Java projects that are intended to be executable from the command line must be built that way and packaged with a MANIFEST.INF file inside its JAR file.  Once built as an executable, it can be executed as `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar <par1  par2 ... parn>`.  In this case, the `par`s will be processed into a String array and passed to the `main(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

1. Of course; the JVM only calls `main(String[])` automatically. It's specifically for taking string args from the command line.
2. It's just another method: while it's almost always used as an entry point, there's no technical reason you can't use it like any other static method. I *wouldn't*, because it's atypical and non-communicative.

Comment: sorry. let me clarify. when i type `java *File*` in the command prompt without any parameters after `*File*`, what is the string used to call the main method? is it just an empty string?

Comment: @qaz It's not "a String", it's an array of strings. If there aren't any command line parameters, the array won't have any elements. This is beyond trivial to test, btw.

Comment: ahh yep my bad. i'll keep in mind to test easily testable stuff like this myself

Answer (score 2):

> In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method whose signature is:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> The modifiers public and static can be written in either order (public static or static public), but the convention is to use public static as shown above. You can name the argument anything you want, but most programmers choose "args" or "argv".
>
> The main method is similar to the main function in C and C++; it's the entry point for your application and will subsequently invoke all the other methods required by your program.
>
> The main method accepts a single argument: an array of elements of type String.
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> This array is the mechanism through which the runtime system passes information to your application.`

You can read some more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) and the main Java documentation, which is very practical, is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Also for your second question, yeah you can do it but I don't suggest it.